# Effect like background-attachment:fixed but with img blocks and position

Tags: css, position

Is there a way to achieve the effect of `background-attachment: fixed`, but rather than using `background-image` use an `<img />` block.

I'm looking to achieve this effect without using `background-image` https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-currying-iop7l

Such that when scroll, the images have not visible seam lines when they transition between.

My layout is as follows

```
<body>
<section><img></section>
<section><img></section>
</body>
```

but no matter what I try I can't get the img to get clipped by it's parent `<section>`.

I tried `position: fixed` for the `img`. I tried it with `z-index` as well.
`position: sticky` doesn't work in this case because the `img` gets pushed up by it's containing parent rather than get clipped.

Comment: I think the only way is the background image, but there is a trick, you can use <img/> tag but with the help of jquery, just pull the img src to a background-image.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to use `img` because it would allow me to set the background of the parent independently.

Comment: Yes thats what I said, Use the `img` tag, but later pull the image src to a background-image with jquery

Comment: Pull the `img` src to the `background-image` of what element?

Comment: Buddy, use img tag with display none on it, with jquery copy the img src, like `<img src="image.png" />` copy the image path `image.png` and put it as a background witgh jquery `$("class-name").css("background-image",image-path-variable)

Comment: to the same elements where the background image works. <section>

Comment: You know that an element can have _multiple_ background images, no?

Comment: @misorude that would prevent right-click save img
@AwsmeSandy i see what you mean now, but if i have to get jquery involved i might as well just use a dynamic clip mask in vanilla js. pure css is preferred like with `background-attachment`

Comment: _“that would prevent right-click save img”_ - you did not say that was a requirement, but specifically said you wanted to use an img element so that you could specify the background independently.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what you want to achieve, but try to work with the "overflow" property on the parent.

```css
[parent_selector]
{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```